# Strange jumping cursor on MacBook Pro 15" Retina mid-2015 El Capitan when typing

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos, display, trackpad

Using MBP (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015), 2.8GHz Intel Core I7 16GB 1600 Mhz DDR3
AMD Radeon R9 M370X 2048 MB
1 TB Apple SSD

Top shelf system. Running OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

While typing, in almost any app or input form, the cursor will often randomly jump to a different place in the text and continue placing my input in the new location. I use the internal keyboard and trackpad most of the time. I work hard to keep my palms off the trackpad. This has become such a prevalent problem the machine is difficult to use for serious work. The keyboard and trackpad could sure use a cleaning by Apple Store or something. But what is the root cause of the jumping cursor. I do have external keyboard and magic mouse but I disable bluetooth to ensure they are not the cause (or it happens when those devices aren't with me).

Been a MBP and other Mac user since around 2004 after Intel and OS X. I have virtual machines with Linux, FreeBSD, (no Windows at the moment) but the VMWare Fusion App isn't running when this happens. Typically I have Chrome open with dozens of tabs, several command terminals, Spotify, Email Client, Skype, Slack, Sublime Text 2, Notes and sometimes a MS Office app. There are not a lot of things running or autoloading. I run regular virus scans weekly and malwarebytes. The machine seems clean of anything malicious. FWIW, I don't use real-time AV, I just do complete system scans 1-2 times a week. I can't say when this started happening exactly but it's been a while now and I'm finally questioning my love for this machine. I have some strange typing stuff on my iPad Air 2 but that's fairly close to the same problem. Anyone have a clue what might be going on here with my Apple systems? I'm actually reluctant to upgrade to a new MBP until I understand what is happening here first.

Despite the huge drive the systems tends to run 80% full with only about 200GB free. I almost always one with an external HDMI monitor if that matters. I generally have nothing plugged into thunderbold and manybe one USB 2 or 3 device to charge my iPhone/iPad Air 2, Apple Watch, external battery, or (forgive me), my Google Fi Nexus 5 I use for Asian travels.

Oh... I do go to Asia and although I am always in English, I do get messages with a lot of Chinese Unicode messages. I sometimes change region or time zone when in Hong Kong or Dongguan. I mention this because it does seem to be about the time strange problems began. But remember, Malwarebytes, Avast AV and other security tools report the machine to be uninfected.

Comment: Is the cursor jumping around when you use a bluetooth Trackpad or the internal trackpad?

Comment: internal trackpad only. I don't have a bluetooth trackpad.